# Insert statement with CASE to avoid duplicate row insertion

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have written the below stored procedure for checking for duplicates before inserting the row into the table.

But I cannot write my `INSERT` statement inside the `CASE`.

How can I write stored procedure for checking the value of `@Ordername` and after that if it is not present then it should be inserted into database .

```
       CREATE PROCEDURE [Test Procedure ]
          (
          @section varchar(70), 
          @mark varchar(70),
          @qty decimal(18,2),
          @Weight decimal(18,2),
          @dateupdateremark int,
          @OrderName varchar(70)
           )
          AS
       BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

       select case(@OrderName)
       when (select OrderName from dbo.tbl_insertxmldetails 
       where(@OrderName) not in (select OrderName from tbl_insertxmldetails))

       then 
       insert into dbo.tbl_insertxmldetails 
       (Section, Mark, QTY,Weight,Dateupdateremark ,OrderName,SystemDate)
       values
       (@Section, @Mark, @QTY,@Weight, @Dateupdateremark,@OrderName,GETDATE())
       else 'File already Exists'
 end
```

Answer (score 2):

Use If not exists clause instead of case statement that will resolve your problem

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Test Procedure ]
          (
          @section varchar(70), 
          @mark varchar(70),
          @qty decimal(18,2),
          @Weight decimal(18,2),
          @dateupdateremark int,
          @OrderName varchar(70)
           )
          AS
       BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;


      if not exists (select OrderName from dbo.tbl_insertxmldetails 
       where(@OrderName) not in (select OrderName from tbl_insertxmldetails))

      Begin

         insert into dbo.tbl_insertxmldetails 
         (Section, Mark, QTY,Weight,Dateupdateremark ,OrderName,SystemDate)
         values
         (@Section, @Mark, @QTY,@Weight, @Dateupdateremark,@OrderName,GETDATE())

      End

       else
           Select 'File already Exists'
```

Comment: Your `else 'File already Exists'` bit doesn't make sense in that context.

Comment: Well, yes, that would compile at least. Although, if you choose to return that result with a `SELECT` statement, you should perhaps consider adding another SELECT just after `INSERT`, returning the result of a *successful* insertion, to make the behaviour of the stored procedure more consistent. However, if I were you, I would probably not return the result with a `SELECT` statement at all. I might use `print 'File already Exists'` instead of `select 'File already Exists'` or simply `RETURN 1` (or, perhaps, `RETURN -1`).

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `NOT IN`, you can just do it this way

```
 IF NOT EXISTS(select OrderName from dbo.tbl_insertxmldetails Where OrderName=@OrderName)
 BEGIN

   insert into dbo.tbl_insertxmldetails 
   (Section, Mark, QTY,Weight,Dateupdateremark ,OrderName,SystemDate)
   values
   (@Section, @Mark, @QTY,@Weight, @Dateupdateremark,@OrderName,GETDATE())
END
   ELSE
     'File already Exists'
```

Comment: What is `ELSE 'File already Exists'` supposed to do? Did you perhaps mean `ELSE PRINT 'File already Exists'`?

Comment: It also Allow duplicate insertion

Comment: rama change your logic as 
if exists then 'File already Exists' else Insert the record.

Comment: I left that for him to implement. I believed he had the rest to fill in